# Incorrect HDFS File URL

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I was trying to access a file present in the HDFS (location: /user/input/UsageSummary.txt). I am not sure what will be the URL for this file.

I tried this url but it did not worked:

`hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/user/input/UsageSummary.txt`

Even I tried these but none of them worked:

`hdfs://localhost:9000/user/input/UsageSummary.txt`

`hdfs://localhost/user/input/UsageSummary.txt`

Please let me know how to find out the correct URL.

**EDIT**

This is the content of `core-site.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>

  <!-- HTTPFS proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.tomcat.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.tomcat.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried running this URL from my browser and it worked:

    hdfs://localhost:8020/user/input/UsageSummary.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output or error you are getting, and what mode are you running hadoop in - local, fully or psuedo distributed?

What do you have set as fs.defaultFS in your core-site.xml? if its set to hdfs://host:port/ you should be able to run something like 
    hdfs dfs -cat /user/input/UsageSummary.txt
or run 
    hdfs dfs -ls / 
to see root ensure directory structure does exist.

Comment: welcome to SO.  These types of questions should be posted as comments on the question rather than as an answer.

Comment: I tried running this URL from my browser and it worked:

    hdfs://localhost:8020/user/input/UsageSummary.txt

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the HDFS resource path is

```
hdfs://<NameNodeHost>:<port>/path to resource
```

If you just want to print a file content, the below is sufficient.

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/input/UsageSummary.txt
```